# How to obtain data from sub query that has self join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

my table:

```
friends(uid_1 int, uid_2 int)
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT a.uid_1
     , a.uid_2 as a2
     , b.uid_1 as b1
     , b.uid_2
  from friend a 
  join friend b
    on a.uid_1 = b.uid_2;
```

I want to obtain a2 and b1 from query for other purposes

So this query now:

```
Select a2,b1
from (SELECT a.uid_1,a.uid_2 as a2,b.uid_1 as b1,b.uid_2
      from friend a join
           friend b
           on a.uid_1=b.uid_2
     )
```

does not work. How do I obtain certain data from a range of displayed data?

Comment: In MySQL, you need an alias after a derived table.  I call this a typo and vote to close.

Comment: Can't you just select uids where uid_1 & uid_2 are equal? Why are you doing a self join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1, you are just missing with a Alias name for your sub query as below-

```
Select a2,b1
from (
    SELECT a.uid_1,a.uid_2 as a2,b.uid_1 as b1,b.uid_2
    from friend a join
    friend b
    on a.uid_1=b.uid_2
) A -- added A as a Alias
```

But number 2, not sure what you are trying to do with the JOIN as your query with implemented JOIN conditions is simply equivalent to below query-

```
SELECT * 
FROM friend 
WHERE uid_1 = uid_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  table name alias for the subquery  eg : Select  ... FROM (subquery ) T

then you can refer the subquery content with a fully qualified  name

```
    Select T.a2, T.b1
    from (SELECT a.uid_1,a.uid_2 as a2, b.uid_1 as b1, b.uid_2 b2
          from friend a join
               friend b
               on a.uid_1=b.uid_2
         ) T
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing alias

```
Select a2,b1
from (SELECT a.uid_1,a.uid_2 as a2,b.uid_1 as b1,b.uid_2
  from friend a join
       friend b
       on a.uid_1=b.uid_2
 ) as temp -- here it is
```